Unable to enter user input as list in python
I expected that the code would ask me for input as many times as I want and then print out the number of times the input has been entered along with the name, capitalized. However, it only prints out the last input with 1 in front of the input
Can you tell where am I wrong

while True:
    try: 
        lst = [
          input('Enter name here: ')
        ]
    except (KeyboardInterrupt): 
        for n in lst:
         print(lst.count(n), n.upper())


You assign lst a list consisting of one item which is the result of user input. And you do this again and again (assigning one item of user input).

You are assigning the lst instead of appeding

Following @MichaelButscher comment you also need to increase n by 1 after each input.

You have to append the name taking from the input to the lst, but instead you are here assigning the lst to the list of only the newest named enter by the user.
Use lst.append(input(...))
Also, you have one more problem in your code, it is that your code will never end unless you closes the terminal, it is because you are handling the KeyboardInterruput error but you are not actually stopping the while loop, so it will never end. for that you have to add break after the list.
I am not using any other data structures (like dictionary) to print the count, I am just use your code with the correction
lst = []
while True:
    try:
        lst.append(input('Enter name here: '))
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print()
        for n in set(lst): # use set so that it will not print data for duplicate names
            print(lst.count(n), n.upper())
        exit() 

Output
Enter name here: asd
Enter name here: asd
Enter name here: asd
Enter name here: a
Enter name here: d
Enter name here: qw
Enter name here: a
Enter name here: sd
Enter name here: asd
Enter name here: 
1 D
1 QW
1 SD
4 ASD
2 A


Other way, is if you only want loop to run n times the you do that too

n = 10
lst = []
for i in range(n):
    lst.append(input('Enter name here: '))
    
print() # just for one line space
for n in set(lst): 
    print(lst.count(n), n.upper())




Aww man thankyou so much . I see where i went wrong

There are some issues in your code like:

Every time you initialize your list that's why it print only last output.
KeyboardInterrupt Handling: The except block will only be executed when a
KeyboardInterrupt exception is raised the list will only contain the last input because the list is reinitialized in each loop iteration.
This line (lst.count(n), n.upper()) line is not correct to handle and display the count of names.

You should use the following code:
l = []

try:
    while True:
        name = input('Enter name here: ')
        l.append(name)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    for name in set(l):
        print(l.count(name), name.capitalize())

